# Creating a multiplot from the output of a user defined function with ggplot2

Tags: r

I created a function to automate creating `ggplot` column plots. However when I call the function it outputs a list:

```
Plotter<- function (df,title){
    Plots <-ggplot2(df,aes(x=mpg,y=wt))+geom_col()+ggtitle(title)
    print(Plots)
    return(Plots)
}

plot1 <- Plotter(data,"test")
plot2 <- Plotter(data,"test2")
```

When I call `ggarrange(plot1,plot2,ncol=2)`,
I get an error stating that `ggarrange` only accepts a `ggplot`,`glist`, but you have a list??

I checked the class of `plot1` and it’s a list?
I also tried converting it to a grob, but that does not work. Can someone please let me know what I’m missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
library(gridExtra)
Plotter<- function (df,title){
  Plots <-ggplot(df,aes(x=mpg,y=wt))+geom_col()+ggtitle(title)
  print(Plots)
  return(Plots)
}
data = data.frame(mpg = 1:10, wt = 1:10)

plot1 <- Plotter(data,"test")
plot2 <- Plotter(data,"test2")
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,ncol=2)
```